# Zend Framework URL Rewrite For SEO

Tags: php, zend-framework, url-rewriting, seo, url-routing

I'm new to Zend, so pls help me out on this one, since I have searched a lot and tried a lot, I really did.

here is the very old question:

this is my current url:

```
www.sample.com/blog/detail/index/id/5
```

wanted:

```
www.sample.com/url-rewrite-tips
```

well, I put following code in the bootstrap.php

```
$router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
                'url-rewrite-tips',
                array(
                     'module'     => 'blog',
                     'controller' => 'detail',
                     'action'     => 'index',
                     'id'         => '5'
                )
);
$router->addRoute('url-rewrite-tips', $route);
```

it was working, but it also is a hardcode. i tried to get param in bootstrap.php, but failed.

Now, I have more than 100 ids. However, I tried to put it in index.pthml, in a foreach(){} , then it fails.
I have rewrite names in the DB for every article, how am I supposed to it?

better not use configs or .htaccess

Thanks In advanced.

Comment: How and what parameter did you fail to try to get in bootstrap?  During bootstrap routing hasn't occurred yet so you can't get any URL parameters from there because they haven't been looked at yet.

Answer (score 0):

What I always do is I add the `routes.ini` execution in bootstrap:

```
protected function _initRoutes()
{
    $this->bootstrap('FrontController');
    $front = $this->getResource('FrontController');
    $config = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/routes.ini', 'production');
    $router = $front->getRouter();
    $router->addConfig($config, 'routes');
}
```

Then in `routes.ini`:

```
[production]

routes.content.route = "/s/:permalink"
routes.content.defaults.controller = "content"
routes.content.defaults.action = "show"
routes.content.reqs.permalink = "[a-z0-9-]+"
```

So now when someone access `http://mydomain.com/s/some-nice-permalink` routing goes to `ContentController` `ShowAction()` method, which takes permalink as param and finds it in database.

Of course you'll have to also write methods for creating unique permalinks in database.